# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint project built in SharePoint 2010. I receive no errors when building the solution but when I try to deploy this solution I receive:

> "Error    4   Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Input
>   string was not in a correct format."

I've also tried to deploy the same WSP file using Powershell however I still receive the same error. I've tried to identify the root cause checking the logs at the time of deployment as well however I couldn't find anything there.

Again I tried removing all the solutions in the package and deploy the WSP. But it gives the same error. Please give me a direction to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're doing something with a variable you shouldn't be. I recommend looking into any areas that you've used parse. Could you post your source code for debugging?

Additionally the best practice method for SharePoint development is to first create your solution writing to a console window (so you can debug it) and then once you're happy with the outcome then and only then move it into the solution. I would recommend looking into this for future reference.